# I have just Installed Flutter, Android Studio, and VS CODE, but I just cant get flutter doctor to eliminate the following error-

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, visual-studio-code

[image]

I also ran the command `flutter doctor --android -licenses` but still it shows the error displayed in the image.

I also tried to install android sdk obsolete package from within Android Studio but the package is pre-installed.

What shall I do?

Please Help me, - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Delete android studio permanently and config folder in "User" folder in C:\ . and Delete "SDK" and reinstall Android studio. it probably solve problem

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will try your suggestion.